# Using JSONP over SSL

Tags: javascript, security, ssl, jsonp

If I want to send information to a server using SSL, presumably that's sensitive information. If I use JSONP to send it to a different domain, that sensitive information must go in the querystring. At a minimum, it seems that this information would be logged by the web server, thus exposing sensitive information. Does using JSONP over SSL make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *returning* data, sure it can make sense, for requesting data though...yes you're going to expose data in the query string that can be logged at several places along the way.

Using SSL to POST the data through your own domain(and you proxying to the other) seems like a better option, if it's possible, so you're not providing data using GET at any point.

Comment: Ah, returning the information. Yeah, I agree on proxying, but in this case, I don't control which domain does and doesn't have SSL.